# How Can i change default font of Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I like to change default font of Ckeditor !

I cant do it and dont see anything about it in Docs .
I can only change the default lable of it !

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting font-size and font-family in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155789/setting-font-size-and-font-family-in-ckeditor)

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_style) these all seem to be defined in **plugins/font/plugin.js.**

{Object} CKEDITOR.config.font_style
The style definition to be used to apply the font in the text. 
Defined in: plugins/font/plugin.js.

```js
config.font_style =
    {
        element  : 'span',
        styles  : { 'font-family' : '#(family)' },
        overrides : [ { element : 'font', attributes : { 'face' : null } } ]
    };
```

{String} CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_defaultLabel Since: 3.0
The text to be displayed in the Font Size combo is none of the available values matches the current cursor position or text selection. 
Defined in: plugins/font/plugin.js.

```js
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '12px';
```

{String} CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_sizes Since: 3.0
The list of fonts size to be displayed in the Font Size combo in the toolbar. Entries are separated by semi-colons (;). Any kind of "CSS like" size can be used, like "12px", "2.3em", "130%", "larger" or "x-small". A display name may be optionally defined by prefixing the entries with the name and the slash character. For example, "Bigger Font/14px" will be displayed as "Bigger Font" in the list, but will be outputted as "14px". 
Defined in: plugins/font/plugin.js.

```js
config.fontSize_sizes = '16/16px;24/24px;48/48px;';
config.fontSize_sizes = '12px;2.3em;130%;larger;x-small';
config.fontSize_sizes = '12 Pixels/12px;Big/2.3em;30 Percent More/130%;Bigger/larger;Very Small/x-small';
```

I am not very savvy with Ckeditor, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In `config.js`:

```
config.contentsCss = '/ckeditor/fonts.css';
config.font_names = 'shabnam';
```

In `fonts.css`:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "shabnam";
   src: url("/fonts/Shabnam.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

Now, it may be all right.
if you want this font to be styled with body tag, you should add this in `fonts.css`:

```
body {
  /* Font */
  font-family: "shabnam";
}
```

In order to change toolbar style, what worked for me was this:

In
`skins/moono-lisa/editor.css`:

```
delete `font:normal normal normal 12px Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,Verdana,Sans-Serif;` from 
     `.cke_reset_all,.cke_reset_all *,.cke_reset_all a,.cke_reset_all textarea`
```