# How to set default font in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to set a default font and font-size for the CKEditor 4

Found this in the CKEditor 4 documentation
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-font_style

Like I want to change the default font to "Comic Sans MS" and the font size to "48"

Tried like this, but not working

```
ckeditorConfig.font_style = {
  element:  'span',
  styles:  { 'font-family': 'Comic Sans MS' },
  overrides:  [ { element: 'font', attributes: { 'face': null } } ]
};

ckeditorConfig.fontSize_style = {
  element:  'span',
  styles:  { 'font-size': '48px' },
  overrides:  [ { element: 'font', attributes: { 'size': null } } ]
};
```

Found this from stack overflow, but no working examples [How Can i change default font of Ckeditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795230/how-can-i-change-default-font-of-ckeditor)

Also setting a span on CKEditor's instanceReady is not helping
[Is there a way to set the default font and font-size in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142277/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-font-and-font-size-in-ckeditor)

----Update---

The above CKEditor config is overriding the CKEditor's Font drop-down option and not affecting the default font. Seems like it overrides the font selected from the drop-down to the one specified in the Config.

Is there any other way to set the default font for CKEditor 4.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please try this  
config.font_style =
    {
        element  : 'span',
        styles  : { 'font-family' : '#(family)','background-color': '#e5ffcd' }
    };

Please mention this inside the config.js file

Comment: Thank you @mariappank. Tried the `font_style` config. But seems like it overrides the font settings from the ckEditor's font drop down and does nothing on the default font.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You want to override the default fonts in dropdown right ?

Comment: No. I want to set the default font of the Editor. Like when we start typing on the editor, I want my default font setting. This can be changed from the drop-down by the end user.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, as you mentioned link  you have instance ready set data method is working fine. can you show your code, what you tried or can you try this
editor.setData('<span style="font-family:Courier New,Courier,monospace;"><br/></span>');

Comment: I got a solution. I had a block of code where the unwanted ckeditor bookmarks were cleaned up. Added a div with some inline styles specific to the font setting, to persist the font styles when thread is saved. For live UI changes, added a style to the ckeditor's parent div, to reflect the font styles while typing the content. `ckeditorConfig.font_style` was not useful.Used `ckeditorConfig.font_defaultLabel` to set the font drop down value of the ckeditor. I can't use the `setData` method to set styles, as it may obstruct some of the  the existing code flow. Thanks for the help @mariappank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for my use case. I had a block of code where the unwanted ckeditor bookmarks were cleaned up. Added a div with some inline styles specific to the font setting, to persist the font styles when thread is saved. For live UI changes, added a style to the ckeditor's parent div, to reflect the font styles while typing the content. `ckeditorConfig.font_style` was not useful.Used `ckeditorConfig.font_defaultLabel` to set the font drop down value of the ckeditor. I can't use the `setData` method to set styles, as it may obstruct some of the the existing code flow.